# why these 2 python lists have different len's?

Tags: python, while-loop, data-science

I have written the following code for adaptive step size RungeKutta RK 4th order integration method.

```
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

rhs_of_diff_Eq_str = "3 * t ** 2"

def first_derivative(t, y): # the first derivative of the function y(t)
    first_derivative_value = 3 * t ** 2
    return first_derivative_value

time_interval_lowerlimit = 0.0
time_interval_upperlimit = 1.0
dt = 0.01
ts = []

y = 0. # initial condition
t = 0. # initial condition
ys_step = ys_halfstep = ys_doublestep = ys = []
dy_min = 0.01
dy_max = 0.1
dt_min = 0.0001
y_tol = 0.0001

no_of_iterations = 0

while(t < 1):
    no_of_iterations += 1

    # for timestep = dt
    k1 = first_derivative(t,          y) 
    k2 = first_derivative(t + dt/2. , y + (dt/2.)*k1)
    k3 = first_derivative(t + dt/2. , y + (dt/2.)*k2)
    k4 = first_derivative(t +  dt   , y +   dt   *k3)
    y_step = y + (dt/6.) * (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4)
    ys_step.append(y_step) # for plotting y vs t, at the end of the script, after integration has finished

    # for timestep = dt / 2
    k1 = first_derivative(t,          y)
    k2 = first_derivative(t + dt/4. , y + (dt/4.)*k1)
    k3 = first_derivative(t + dt/4. , y + (dt/4.)*k2)
    k4 = first_derivative(t + dt/2. , y + (dt/2.)*k3)
    y_halfstep = y + (dt/12.) * (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4)
    ys_halfstep.append(y_halfstep)
    
    # for timestep = dt * 2
    k1 = first_derivative(t,          y)
    k2 = first_derivative(t +  dt ,   y +  dt   * k1)
    k3 = first_derivative(t +  dt ,   y +  dt   * k2)
    k4 = first_derivative(t + 2.*dt,  y + 2.*dt * k3)
    y_doublestep = y + (dt/3.) * (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4)
    ys_doublestep.append(y_doublestep)


    if (abs(y_step) <= y_tol): # fix the timestep to dt_min because otherwise we divide by 0 in comparisons below
        if (dt != dt_min):
            dt = dt_min
        new_y = y_step

    else: # can modify the timestep if needed
        if ( (abs(y_step) > y_tol)  and ( (abs(y_step - y_halfstep)/abs(y_step))  > dy_max ) ): # error is too large
            dt = dt / 2.
            new_y = y_halfstep
        else:
            if ( (abs(y_step) > y_tol) and ( (abs(y_step - y_doublestep)/abs(y_step)) < dy_min ) ) : # error too small, can increase dt
                dt = 2. * dt
                new_y = y_doublestep
            else: # timestep is just right! keep it as it is and return y_step (i.e. the y-value computed using timestep = dt)
                new_y = y_step
    
    y = new_y
    # print("y is :")
    # print(y)
    # print(len(y)) # error, object of type 'float' has no len()
    ys.append(y)
    # print("t is: ")
    # print(t)
    ts.append(t)
    t += dt

print(len(ys)) # 
print(len(ts)) # 
print("no of iterations: ")
print(no_of_iterations)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(ts, ys, label='y values', color='red')
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title("RK4 adaptive step-size integration for dy/dt = f(y,t) \n" + "f(y,t) = " + rhs_of_diff_Eq_str)
plt.savefig("RK4_adaptive_step_size_results.pdf", bbox_inches='tight')
```

This results in error at the plotting instructions due to the 2 lists `ts` and `ys` having different number of elements.

I have been looking at the code for a while now and I don't see the reason why the `ys` always have 4 times the number of elements in the list `ts` after the script exits from the while-loop.

Can you please help me, maybe it's something obvious?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issues stile happen from this line `ys_step = ys_halfstep = ys_doublestep = ys = []`, there is a created four list but all refers the same memories and when you append the element one of that list it stile append the all that lists.

You can only change the as following:

```py
ys_step = []
ys_halfstep = []
ys_doublestep = []
ys = []
```

it will worked.

Comment: wow, fantastic! thanks , I really appreciate it! I would have spent a lot of time looking at the code and not noticing this mistake/misunderstanding of mine. it perfectly works now with the change you wrote in the answer. thanks!

Comment: Four lists are not created; *one* list is created, with four separate names referring to it. The distinction between names and values in Python is critically important.